# Grant permission to post a new node of content-type 2 if previous node of his content-type 1 has a state of approved

Tags: rules, workflows

I'm using the Workflow module for an article submission contest website.

I have two roles:

1. Referee
2. Participant

The whole workflow is the following.

- Participant users log in, submit their summary article
- System sends a confirmation e-mail to the participant users
- Referee users log in, check the submission, and approve/deny the
  submission
- System sends another e-mail letting the participant know the result
- When approved, participant users may send their article
- Referee users check the new submission, approve/deny and publish
- System sends a congratulation e-mail

The part that got me hooked with the Rules module is implementing this point.

- When the referee users approve the *Summary Article* node via the Workflow module, it gives the participant permission to create a new *Full Article* node

I'd really appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `Roles`.

1. Role 1 -> has permission to create summary (content type 1)
2. Role 2 -> has permission to create full article (content type 2)

you can assign `Role 1` to users by default.

Next you create a rule like

> Event : Summary gets approved
>   Action : Add user role

The way you create the rule depends on whether you are using `Workflow Node` or `Workflow field`

If you are using **Workflow Node** then the rule  will be

> Event : Workflow state has changed 
>   Condition : Check the state

If you are using **Workflow Field** then the rule will be

> Event : After updating existing node 
>   Condition : Do a data comparison for the workflow field with the state ID.

Action will be **Add user role**, that is **Role 2**